# What would be an optimal CPU to get for a Minecraft Server for around 100$ if any? (50 player server)

Tags: processor, gaming, pc, server, performance

I started hosting a MC server on a dedicated machine at home for a week now and I wanted to get something a bit better, it runs with a few plugins - 5GB ram dedicated to the server.

So, my budget is around £100 just for the cpu, (motherboard in that range is also great! xD) new or used. I want to know what would be an optimal CPU for a rough 50 players online, with plugins, and 15 chunk render distance.
At the moment i run a AMD Athlon x4 880k and 8GB 2133Mhz memory DDR3 (5G to server) but even at 4 players online i see the MSPT over 35 and the server TPS often goes below 20 (50 players is unreachable xD) - currently on latest build of Purpur.jar and PopOS! Linux.

I have read online that Xeon is better, NO, Ryzen is better, no this, no that.... so..... WHAAT ONE IS BETTER LMAO! I have heard that the only thing that matters is Single Core Performance, so an Intel core i3-10105F is within my budget as it beats a 3700x in this application. Is this good for what i need, or can i get better in any way..... any feedback is welcome. Thanks! :D

if neither of these cpu's could run 50 players at once, how much would they be able to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a Ryzen 3 3100 and overclock it. Also run Ubuntu server, because its faster than Pop OS. Also make sure your internet connection is fast enough, because I host a minecraft server myself and I am bottlenecked by my upload speed. If the cpu is too expensive, you can cheap out on the motherboard, any B450 board will do. Forget Xeons, those are too expensive for what they do.

Comment: This info is greatly appreciated. If i may ask though, according to this website: https://www.cpubenchmark.net/singleThread.html
The i3-10105f has better single core performance than a R3 3100. So, would this overclock make it perform much better than the i3 or is there other variables im not taking into account of, thaanks! :D

Comment: OCing would make it better for the ryzen, and I think it will push it really close to the i3 or even further. Also the mobo's are mostly cheaper on the ryzen. And see more benchmarks, because a sample size of 1 doesn't tell you much about cpu performance

Comment: i see, i see, the i3 costs 75£ for me whereas the R3 costs 120£, so i think the extra cost covers a more expensive motherboard. As for cpu performance i do suppose the R3 will generally outperform the I3, but i only need it dedicated for a mc server. so i guess im stuck between the two now. As for player count, how many players would i expect to be able to handle at once with the R3 3100?

Comment: If your internet connection is good enough (especially upload speed) and you don't have too laggy farms/transportation methods, you can handle quite a lot of players (75 should be doable). But your main limitation is gonna be your internet connection with that cpu and if you have laggy farms, don't expect to go much higher than 10 (those are pretty hard to run)

Comment: sounds fine then, i get 20Mbps upload and as far as i can tell it takes 3 people for the upload to get to 1Mbps. So in theory i could get to 60 people then.

Comment: the recomended cpu is already below the 20+ player recomendation that the minecraft fandom sets( see https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Server/Requirements/Dedicated). I'd also recomend against overclocking for a server. It can affect stability and with the default cooler will add little to no actual performance gain. A custom cooler could be added,but at the budget level you're looking it's probably better to look for a slightly higher end cpu.

Comment: Im still a little confused, the fandom thing you recommended said an i5-i7 was needed for 20+ but as far as im concerned they only mainly offer more cores/threads.etc. And from research i believe that the server only uses 1 core, hence multiple would be wasted. So if the i3 can outperform and i5 or i7 theoretically it would be better? It states (i5-i7) but doesnt specify what ones, like latest, or literally the 1st gen i7 xD. Thanks :D

Comment: True... But I have heared that you can run multiple server instances in one world, but that is not practical in an SMP. But if you do it that way, you can get more out of a ryzen 5

Comment: I would like to point out that Xeons are popular on a budget because there is a huge market for used servers and the Xeon CPUs pulled from those servers. $100 for a brand new CPU might get you less performance than $100 for a Xeon that is a few years old but has more cores. Many of the Xeon CPU models are the same chips as i5/i7 CPUs but they cut back TurboBoost speeds to keep them really stable and enable server-oriented features like ECC memory.

Comment: so. is the i3 a good option for the mc server as it has higher single core performance than my Ryzen 7 3700x and it already can run servers flawlessly? will it (i assume it will) give me better or the same performance as my Ryzen 7??

Comment: If that is the case in a lot of benchmarks, yes